# Multiple iterations for boarding/exiting rates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble getting this function to work properly. I would like to take a list, run the values in order through the function according to the number of iterations given. The function I have seems to work but the iterations are running the length of the list before moving to the next iteration.

```
iterations = 10
boarding = [10, 20, 10]
exiting = [30, 25, 15]
current = 0
for e in range(1,iterations + 1):
    for x,y in zip(boarding, exiting):
        if e == 1:
            current = 0
            print( '{0:^10d}{1:^10d}{2:^10d}{3:^10d}'.format(e, current, x, y))
        else:
            current = x - (min(current,y)) + x
            print( '{0:^10d}{1:^10d}{2:^10d}{3:^10d}'.format(e, current, x, y))
```

the output is:

```
    1         0         10        30    
    1         0         20        25    
    1         0         10        15    
    2         20        10        30    
    2         20        20        25    
    2         5         10        15    
    3         15        10        30    
    3         25        20        25    
    3         5         10        15    
    4         15        10        30    
    4         25        20        25    
    4         5         10        15    
    5         15        10        30    
    5         25        20        25    
    5         5         10        15    
    6         15        10        30    
    6         25        20        25    
    6         5         10        15    
    7         15        10        30    
    7         25        20        25    
    7         5         10        15    
    8         15        10        30    
    8         25        20        25    
    8         5         10        15    
    9         15        10        30    
    9         25        20        25    
    9         5         10        15    
    10        15        10        30    
    10        25        20        25    
    10        5         10        15
```

I'm not sure why it it printing three times per iteration.

Comment: Your print statements are inside the `for x, y in zip(....):`, so you're going to print a line for each pair of boarding, exiting pairs.  The code is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: `boarding` and `exiting` both have three elements, you loop over the `zip()` of them, which will yield three tuples and thus execute the code inside the loop three times, which has your print statement. So it would be expected that the print statements are executed three times for each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: What do you expect/want to be receiving?

Comment: I would like it so that the function takes the the list in order and runs it though to get 'current'. Iteration 1 would run the first values in each list, iteration 2 runs the second etc... when the list no longer has any values to run, the function should go back and run the values in order again until the final iteration. 10 in this case. Finally, I would like to print each iteration that is ran so that I can make a table with it later.